# Conversion error on host variable or parameter *N

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange

I am getting this Error on Insert statement to AS400 database, using Java with JDBC.

Answer (score 7):

I figured it out, I had a numeric field with length 4 and decimal digits 2, In my insert I was trying to insert 100 in this numeric field which gave this error.

```
I altered the table and made it numeric with length 9 and decimal digits 2 
and the insert worked.
```

even though the error says "Conversion error", actually its the wrong field length.

Comment: Makes sense.  It was trying to convert a 3,0 value to a 4,2 value when it failed.

Answer (score 1):

I ran in to this issue when a table was updated from 2 digits to 3 for user ID's and the query inserts in to a history table where the history table was not updated to 3 digits for the user id.  Used `Alter Table` to correct the history table and all is well.

```
alter table "Table Name" ALTER COLUMN "COLUMN NAME" SET DATA TYPE NUMERIC(3)
```

The error message is not intuitive:

> Conversion error on variable or parameter *N (#-302) [IBM][System
>   iAccess ODBC Driver][DB2 for i5/OS]SQL0012 - Correlation without
>   qualification occurred for column "columnname" to table "Tablename".
>   (#12)

Answer (score 0):

I got this error today running the following query:

```
select *
from mytable
where invoice_date >= '2019-01-01'
```

Turned out invoice "date" is not a date...  it's a decimal that impersonates a date.  Poor database design, perhaps, but nonetheless the simple fix was:

```
select *
from mytable
where invoice_date >= 20190101
```

Comment: "Poor database design, perhaps"  I work at a company still using DB2 on an older AS400 system. They designed their column to hold dates like this too (A long time ago).  It's kind of a pain but I have gotten used to it. Must have been written in the textbooks to do it this way for some reason.

Comment: @eaglei22 - If your dates were numeric YYYYMMDD you were lucky! Some places had 6-digit numbers, or the year was in the least significant digits rather than the most significant. The issue is that if you go back far enough, there *was no such thing* as a proper date data type. So numeric was the only sensible choice.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was I overlooked the fact that I had single quotes around my parameter place holder. So I was getting a, `6 -- Numeric data that is not valid.` error.

So, for example:

```
select someColumn
From   favTable
where  someOtherColumn = '?'

command.Parameters.Add("decVal", OleDbType.Decimal, 10).Value = model.someDecVal;
```

Correcting to:

```
select someColumn
From   favTable
where  someOtherColumn = ?
```

solved my issue.

Looks easy to catch here, but with big queries, this can be easily overlooked. Wasted about an hour on this.